# jquery: why css('width') returns different value than width()

Tags: jquery, css, width

When I run following code:

```
        node = $('.period')
        alert(node.width() + ' ' + node.css('width'))
```

i get '0 144px'. How is that possible?

Comment: Please include the associated HTML

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe you're calling it on $(document).ready, and as **width()** *Gets the current computed, pixel, width of the first matched element.*, it'd be 0 as it has not been rendered yet...
**css('width')** however reads from the css stylesheet, which would be already available.

Comment: I think this is right!  I called it as a click and it computed correctly.

Comment: Does it apply to tab loading (I am using jquery ui tabs, not document ready) too? It seems so, but I would like to get sure.

Comment: I've actually never used jQuery UI. You could easily find out by trying to get the value at a later time (onClick for example).

Comment: If you want to be sure everything is loaded, you can use $(window).load