# Target an Element whose Width Wasn't Defined Explicitly in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting width: auto in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557718/detecting-width-auto-in-jquery)

Using jQuery, how do we find out `<div>`s whose width had not been *explicitly* set up in CSS, regardless inline  or non-inline. For example:

```
#outer-box {
  width: 100px;
}
#inside-box {
  /* width isn't set explicitly. */
  background-color: #000;
}

<div id="outer-box">
   <div id="inside-box">...</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to get a hold of only the `div#inside-box` based on the fact its width wasn't explicitly defined via the CSS.

Comment: This might give you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1212815/681807

Comment: I put together a demo for your question at http://jsfiddle.net/sCG7V/ Have I understod your question correctly?

Comment: Similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000108/how-can-i-tell-if-a-particular-css-property-is-inherited-with-jquery

Comment: This is already asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557718/detecting-width-auto-in-jquery). According to the accepted answer, there is no way to do it.

Comment: +1 for @Stefan for making the jsFiddle demo. By the way, how do you see the output of `console.log` in jsFiddle?

Comment: @Siku-Siku.Com `console.log` shows it´s output in the browser console. Use Chrome or Firefox (with Firebug), hotkey F12. It can also be possible to view in IE but that´s not as easy.